# How to let Mercurial hg diff recognize .strings files in xcode?

Tags: xcode, mercurial

for example, when I do 
"diff -r  r1 -r r2 client/src/en.lproj/Localizable.strings"

I got the following but it doesn't give me the diff details and .strings file is just a text file.
Binary file client/src/en.lproj/Localizable.strings has changed

Answer (score 0):

found the answer from link below. post here for people got the same question.
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BinaryFiles

add -a to it for example "diff -a -r r1 -r r2 myfile.strings